# Not all DataTriggers of StackPanel are working

Tags: wpf, background, storyboard, datatrigger, stackpanel

I have a button which shows a text and an image:
For this I use a StackPanel with a TextBlock and an Image inside of it.

When the variable "ActiveState" changes the Background of the StackPanel should change too, for this I use DataTriggers

ActiveState=0 -> Red / 
ActiveState=1 -> Blue / 
ActiveState=2 -> blinking Blue (for this I use a Storyboard and a Color Animation)

The blinking Trigger (Value=2) is working fine, but the two other Triggers (Value=0 + Value=1) are not working.

When I remove the Background of the Stackpanel (Background="Transparent") the first two Triggers are working but the last one get the following Exception:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll*

*Additional information: Background property does not point to a dependencyobject in path '(0).(1)'*

This is my code:

```
<Button>
  <Button.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="SelectButtonStackpanel" Background="Transparent">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Uniform" Height="40" Width="40"/>                    
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Style.Triggers>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveState}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                            </DataTrigger>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveState}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            </DataTrigger>

                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveState}" Value="2">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                To="Blue" Duration="0:0:1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                >
                                            </ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>

                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                Duration="0:0:1"
                                                >
                                            </ColorAnimation>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>

                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
            </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Do you have any idea how I get all three Triggers working?

best regards
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you directly set `Background="Transparent"` on the StackPanel, this has higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) than a value set from a Style Setter. So remove the direct assignment and add another Setter for the default Background.

Besides that, if you want to animate `Background.Color` you should always explictly assign SolidColorBrushes instead of predefined Brushes like `Background="Red"`.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="SelectButtonStackpanel">
    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveState}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveState}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ActiveState}" Value="2">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                    To="Blue" Duration="0:0:1"
                                    AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                </ColorAnimation>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
</StackPanel>
```